# How to invoke another servlet in a servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

As title metioned, How to invoke another servlet in a servlet and get the invoked servlet response?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`RequestDispatcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) instance which is available through the `HttpServletRequest` instance.

However, if you're looking at getting hold of the single instance held by the servlet container [like using the [`getServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServlet%28java.lang.String%29) method in the `ServletContext` instance], it's an entirely different story. The servlet specs have purposefully deprecated the operation which might allow such an option. But, if you *really* want to invoke one servlet while executing the other one, use the `include` method of the `RequestDispatcher` instead of the `forward` method.

Answer (score 1):

[See here:](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getNamedDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29)

```
getServletContext().getNamedRequestDispatcher("servletName")
    .forward(request, response);
```

However I'd assume there are better options. For example move the code you need to a helper class / utility method, and invoke it.

As I come to think of it, you may want another thing: call a servlet separately. For that you need:

```
InputStream is = new URL(urlOfTheServlet).openStream();
IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
```

(this is using apache commons-io to copy the input stream to the output stream of the current request)

Answer (score 0):

Use ServletContext or current request to get RequestDispatcher, and then use RequestDispatcher forward() or include().

Can use Spring MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpServletResponse to create new request and response instead of use current request.

Example:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);

MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
servletRequest.setServerName(request.getServerName() );
servletRequest.setServerPort(request.getServerPort() );
servletRequest.setSession(request.getSession() );
servletRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET.name() );

servletRequest.setRequestURI(url);
servletRequest.setParameters(parameters);

MockHttpServletResponse servletResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
// Use include() instead of forward(). Similar as client HttpClient GET
dispatcher.include(servletRequest, servletResponse);
String content = servletResponse.getContentAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String destinationBlockAccount  ="./BlockAccount";
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(destinationBlockAccount));
```

Furthermore you can sending a parameter like directly from JSP:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("./GetAccount?accountID="+accountID));
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code.

Comment: It means that you have a servlet named BlockAccount with URL pattern /BlockAccount. Then we can redirect to this servlet. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371220/what-is-the-difference-between-response-sendredirect-and-request-getrequestdis

Comment: and https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html