# Spring MVC "duplicates" parts of the URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple `@Controller` within a `spring-mvc` environment. This is the Controller:

```java
@Controller
public class MessageController {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MessageController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/messages/{userId}/{messageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Message getMessage(@PathVariable("userId") String uid,
            @PathVariable("messageId") String msgid) {
        LOG.trace("GET /message/{}/{}", uid, msgid);
        return new Message();
    }
}
```

This is the servlet-mapping in `web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>Messaging Service</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>messaging</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>messaging</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I start the app via jetty and run a request against `/messages/abc/def`, I get the following log:

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/messages/{userId}/{messageId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public ....Message ....MessageController.getMessage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/messages/abc/messages/abc/def] in DispatcherServlet with name 'messaging'
```

What did I do wrong here? The request definitely only contains `/messages/abc/def`, why is this internally translated to `/messages/abc/messages/abc/def`?

Comment: Please, show `<servlet-mapping>` section of `web.xml` file.

Comment: I added `web.xml` to the question.

Comment: Hi, I met this issue. Did you have any solution?

Comment: Yes, see the first Answer, annotate your method with ```@ResponseBody```.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess it's related to default view name resolution.

If you want a value returned by your handler method to be encoded as response body (in JSON, XML, etc), you need to annoate the method with `@ResponseBody`, or annotate the whole controller with `@RestController` (in Spring 4.x).

Otherwise, Spring tries to render a view with your return as model attribute. And since you didn't provide a name of a view to render, Spring tries to deduce it from request URL.

Comment: Annotating with `@RestController` actually fixed the mapping-problem, though I now still receive a `406 Not Acceptable`

Comment: Fixed the 406 by adding `jackson-mapper-asl` to the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @axtvat, pay attention to the differences between @Cotroller and @RestController, @RestController fixed the issue for me.
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-framework-restcontroller-vs-controller

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file named `messaging-servlet.xml` that declares the web application context?
By default because you have named the DispatcherServlet messaging, Spring will try to locate that file.

Comment: Of course, I do have this file. It's just simple containing:
    <context:component-scan base-package="o.r.s.messaging"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: Then you probably need to add @ResponseBody to getMessage to instruct Spring to return the value as is. This however means that you have to have some sort of message converter such as MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (for Json using the Jackson 2 library)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by replacing `@Controller` with `@RestController`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solved the problem for me. Using @RestController did not redirect but just printed the correct url (the url without the duplication) on the screen. I found this other solution that worked.
[What is the difference between response.sendRedirect() and request.getRequestDispatcher().forward(request,response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371220/what-is-the-difference-between-response-sendredirect-and-request-getrequestdis)

Answer (score 0):

**If your RequestMapping `value` happens to reference properties** [which I admit the OP did not]..

ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "${reference.to.an.application.properties.value}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

.. **then make sure to consider how the property value is resolved; especially if there might be any [overriding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) happening in resolution.**

`classpath root application.properties` ex:

```
reference.to.an.application.properties: /some/path/
reference.to.an.application.properties.value: ${reference.to.an.application.properties}/{ID}
```

If `reference.to.an.application.properties` is also defined somewhere else [additionally], that is **overriding** the same-named property key in  properties file (because of [Spring properties precedence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)); somewhere else (in my case, [OpenShift properties](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/environment-dependent-property-management-strategies-openshift-pipelines) [which are passed by OpenShift as environment variables to Spring]) for ex:

```
reference.to.an.application.properties: /some/path/{ID}
```

Then (by overriding precedence) `reference.to.an.application.properties.value` would resolve to `/some/path/{ID}/{ID}` (thus the duplicated URL path), and not `/some/path/{ID}`