# Duplicating url - Resteasy, Spring, HTML

Tags: java, html, spring, jboss, resteasy

[Spring MVC "duplicates" parts of the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421469/spring-mvc-duplicates-parts-of-the-url)
I looked at the previous link but the answers did not work and did not seem relevant (unless I'm doing something wrong).

My jboss-web.xml root is "/portal"

I have an jsp doc (with only html in it) that posts to a java controller that authenticates a username and password. The formaction is "portal/index".

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validation()" formaction="portal/index"/>
```

The controller's class level path annotation is "portal". The method that I want it to post to has a path annotation "/index".

```
@Controller
@Path("portal")
public class TheController
{....}

@POST
@Path("/index")
public Response login()
{....}
```

If the password and username are correct, then the method will forward to home.jsp. Otherwise, it will go back to index.jsp. For some reason, when I submit the form with the incorrect username and password the 1st time, it will go back to "portal/portal/index" (the form will show up) and if I submit it incorrectly a 2nd time, it will go to "portal/portal/portal/index" and the security filter it goes through will return a 404 not found. What is wrong with my set up that is leading to the duplicating URL?

Comment: if your application root is portal, why you using @path("portal") on controller ?

Comment: I've tried it without the @path("portal") and the problem persists. Originally, I thought you needed the path annotations to match the formaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using /index in form action, you are using relative path, I think that is causing the issue.
Also remove @path("portal") from your controller.

Update:
Try this in formaction
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index"

Comment: When I did this, it got rid of everything so after a submit, it went to localhost/index

Comment: thn try /portal/index