# JSP sendRedirect with return not working

Tags: java, html, jsp

First of all, look at my page [InterFace of My WebSite IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix9Or.png)

I use file **index.jsp** with parameter **view** (**view** is a path of jsp file I want it to show in `<jsp:include>` as a iframe. I declare all **view** in an Enum like:

```
public enum FView {
    HomePage, LogIn, SignUp, Profile, UpdateProfile
}
```

In my **index.jsp**

```
<%
String viewParam = request.getParameter("view");
if (viewParam == null)
    viewParam = "HomePage";
FView f = FView.valueOf(viewParam);

String pageToView = "";
switch (f)
{
    case HomePage:
        pageToView = "page/viewArticles.jsp";
        break;
    case LogIn:
        pageToView = "login.jsp";
        break;
    case Profile:
        pageToView = "page/viewProfile.jsp";
        break;
    default:
        pageToView = "../login.jsp";
        break;
}%>
<jsp:include page="main.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="page" value="<%= pageToView %>
</jsp:include>
```

In my **main.jsp**

```
<div id="header"></div> <!-- <jsp:include> header here, I don't mention all of it.-->
<div id="content">
      <jsp:include page="<%= request.getParameter("page")%>"/> //RED RECTANGLE HERE
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

I have a page that shows user's profile **index.jsp?view=Profile** (the path of file is *WebContent/page/viewProfile.jsp*). I want that when I access to this page without logging in, it will redirect to my login page **index.jsp?view=LogIn** (the path of file is *WebContent/login.jsp*). Here is the code:

```
<%  
Object user_session = session.getAttribute("user_session");;

String usernameFromSession = null;
if (user_session != null)
    usernameFromSession = user_session.toString();
else
{
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?view=LogIn");//any url
    return;
}%>   
<p>This is the profile page</p>
```

Knows that *usernameFromSession* is null. When I reload the page, it shows a white page, nothing even p tag. When I remove *return*, it shows content (p tag above) of the Profile page.
But if I use the primitive path: `localhost:8088:......./page/viewProfile.jsp` instead of `localhost:8088:....index.jsp?view=Profile`,it worked. So how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete code. How do you get session and pass user_session attribute to session?
Also which behavior do you expect from your code?

sendRedirect should be

```
response.sendRedirect("http://google.com");
```

Comment: The session is not important. It's null now, and I want that if it's null (at profile.jsp) sendRedirect to login.jsp. And my sendRedirect is 'response.sendRedirect("index.jsp")' , I use localhost. Thank you.

Comment: Does response.sendRedirect("index.jsp") work as you expect?

Comment: @ThinhPhan see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20371272/17300) ... as fg78nc says, you should use the protocol `http://` if you're redirecting externally like your google.com test, but plain `"index.jsp"` should work because sendRedirect is relative to the _current URL_ unless it's an absolute path (starts with `/` or `http[s]://`)

Comment: @StephenP I try any url inside sendRedirect but nothing happens. I use `request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);` as your link and it worked. But I want to use `sendRedirect ` because I want it to go to index.jsp absolutely ( forward() does not change the url). If there's no solution. Maybe I have to use forward(). Tks u.

Comment: You shall use return after redirecting;  after sendRedirect