# How can I call from one servlet file to another servlet file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

I am using net beans 7.1 and I create one JSP file with two servlet files.
like:

```
index.jsp  --->servlet1.java  --->servlet2.java
```

I give some value from `index.jsp` file and send to `servlet1.java`.

In this `servlet1.java` file I call `servlet2.java` file.

Then it throws `NullPointerException`. How can I solve this?

My code like this:

### index.jsp

```
<form  action="servlet1" method="post">
```

### servlet1.java

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        
                              ..................
                              ..................
                              ..................
        servlet2 ob=new servlet2();
        ob.doPost(request, response);
                              ..................
                              ..................
                              ..................
       }
```

Then it throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496770/how-to-invoke-another-servlet-in-a-servlet

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

#### RequestDispatcher

> Defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends them to any resource (such as a servlet, HTML file, or JSP file) on the server.

---

## Update

No need to create an object of servlet manually, just simply use `RequestDispatcher` to call servlet because web container controls the *lifecycle*  of servlet.

From Oracle JavaEE docs [Servlet Lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html)

The lifecycle of a servlet is controlled by the container in which the servlet has been deployed.
When a request is mapped to a servlet, the container performs the following steps.

1. If an instance of the servlet does not exist, the web container

   - Loads the servlet class.
   - Creates an instance of the servlet class.
   - Initializes the servlet instance by calling the init method. Initialization is covered in [Creating and Initializing a Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html).
2. Invokes the service method, passing request and response objects. Service methods are discussed in [Writing Service Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafv.html).

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying here,

```
servlet2 ob=new servlet2();
ob.doPost(request, response);
```

Its not necessary to create an object explicitly for a servlet, Web container creates an instance for a servlet and shares it during the app's **lifetime** . Though you have created an object here, it will return the existing object only.

You can is instead go for *Request Dispatcher or page Redirect*.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly!